# Stringindexoutofboundsexception in android

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to create a calculator app.IN order to avoid duplication of operators i am checking if the previous character in the string is an operator.But i am getting stringindexoutofboundsexception when i type in the third character.

```
package com.example.calculatorproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText txtresult;
    ImageButton ib_backspace;
    String result="";
    char  value;
    Button btnc,btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9,btn0,btn_add,btn_sub,btn_multi,btn_divide,btn_decimal,btn_equal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtresult=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtresult);
        ib_backspace=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_backspace);
        txtresult.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        btnc=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnC);
        btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        btn0=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        btn_add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btn_sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sub);
        btn_multi=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_multi);
        btn_divide=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_divide);
        btn_decimal=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_decimal);
        btn_equal=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_equal);

        ib_backspace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                result=txtresult.getText().toString();
                if(result.length()!=0)
                {
                result = result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
                setresult();
                }


            }
        });
        btnc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                result="";
                setresult();

            }
        });
        btn0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                result+="0";
                setresult();

            }
        });
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                result+="1";
                setresult();

            }
        });
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+="2";
        setresult();

    }
});
btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+="3";
        setresult();
    }
});
btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+="4";
        setresult();
    }
});
btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+="5";
        setresult();
    }
});
btn6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+="6";
        setresult();
    }
});
btn7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+="7";
        setresult();
    }
});
btn8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+="8";
        setresult();

    }
});
btn9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+="9";
        setresult();

    }
});
btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        value=result.substring(result.length()-1).charAt(result.length()-1);
        if((value=='+')||(value=='-')||(value=='*')||(value=='/')||(value=='.'))
        {
            result=(result.substring(0,result.length()-1))+"+";
            setresult();
        }
        else
        {
        result+="+";
        setresult();
        }

    }
});
btn_sub.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        value=result.substring(result.length()-1).charAt(result.length()-1);
        if((value=='+')||(value=='-')||(value=='*')||(value=='/')||(value=='.'))
        {
            result=result.substring(0,result.length()-1)+"-";
            setresult();
        }
        else
        {
        result+="-";
        setresult();
        }

    }
});
btn_divide.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        value=result.substring(result.length()-1).charAt(result.length()-1);
        if((value=='+')||(value=='-')||(value=='*')||(value=='/')||(value=='.'))
        {
            result=result.substring(0,result.length()-1)+"/";
            setresult();
        }
        else
        {
        result+="/";
        setresult();
        }

    }
});
btn_multi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        value=result.substring(result.length()-1).charAt(result.length()-1);
        if((value=='+')||(value=='-')||(value=='*')||(value=='/')||(value=='.'))
        {
            result=result.substring(0,result.length()-1)+"*";
            setresult();
        }
        else
        {
        result+="*";
        setresult();
        }   
    }
});

btn_decimal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        result+=".";
        setresult();    

    }
});

btn_equal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});


    }
    public void setresult()
    {
        txtresult.setText(result);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

For eg if i type "9+5-*" as the expression the * should replace the - sign.But even when i type 9+5 there is a stringoutofboundsexception when i type +.Please help!!

The logcat

```
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): Process: com.example.calculatorproject, PID: 1492  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at com.example.calculatorproject.MainActivity$14.onClick(MainActivity.java:175)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)  
05-15 06:03:50.317: E/AndroidRuntime(1492):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the troublesome line is value=result.substring(result.length()-1).charAt(result.length()-1);

Comment: could you please log the length of the result variable on line 174, and post the result here?

Comment: You've provided 261 lines of code, most of which are irrelevant to the problem. I suspect that if you take the time to produce a shorter example which will make it easier to diagnose the issue, you'll find the problem yourself.

Comment: (Hint: look at `result.substring(result.length()-1).charAt(result.length()-1);` carefully. How long is `result.substring(result.length()-1)` going to be? Then think about what argument you'll be providing to `charAt`.)

Comment: Your aren't validating if result variable is empty. Just add validation this `if (result==null || result.length() == 0) return;` in the begin of each method that uses result variable

Comment: @betorcs: That's not the only problem though...

Comment: fixed now sub=result.substring(result.length()-1);
  value=sub.charAt(0);

Comment: I have set the result as "" at  class level.

Answer (score 1):

This line is broken for any string with a length other than 1:

```
value = result.substring(result.length()-1).charAt(result.length()-1);
```

Consider different lengths:

- 0 (`result` is an empty string): `result.substring(result.length() - 1)` will fail as you're calling `result.substring(-1)`. Bang.
- 1 (`result` is a single-character string): `result.substring(0)` returns a one-character string (equivalent to `result)` and then `charAt(0)` returns that single character
- 2 or more: `result.substring(result.length() - 1)` returns a one-character string, and then you're calling `charAt` with a value more than 0. Bang.

If you're just trying to find the last character of the string, you want:

```
value = result.charAt(result.length() - 1);
```

There's no need for a `substring` call.

I'd also strongly urge you to consider using more local variables and fewer instance variables. Why is `value` an instance variable for example? Why is `result` an instance variable when you basically want to manipulate the text box contents?